# How to unit test Vue.js components that use nuxt-i18n

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

If I try to run the thing below (with `yarn run jest`), I get **TypeError: _vm.$t is not a function**, because `SearchField` is using a translation (`"$t('search')"`).

```
import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import SearchField from "@/components/ui/SearchField";

describe("SearchField", () => {
  const wrapper = mount(SearchField);

  it("renders correctly", () => {
    expect(wrapper.element).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

If I add the following three lines at the beginning, I get **TypeError: Cannot read property '_t' of undefined** instead.

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueI18n from "vue-i18n";
Vue.use(VueI18n);
```

Comment: well you should provide mock for `$t` - something like this `mount(SearchField, { mocks: { $t: () => {} }. })`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

nuxt-i18n is an external library, not your own code, so the test good practices ask us to just mock the translation library and its needed functions (`$t` in this case).

The following code should solve your problem:

```
describe("SearchField", () => {
  const wrapper = mount(SearchField);

  it("renders correctly", () => {
    mocks: {
      $t: (msg) => msg
    }
    expect(wrapper.element).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

More information on this approach can be found [here](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#mocks).